# Make old data read-only

Tags: sql-server

In a database project that I am currently working on there is a requirement that at a certain point in time 'old' data should be changed to read only. Is this possible in SQL Server?

I can't change the table permission as the read only permission should only apply to data that is older than a certain threshold i.e. users should still be able to add and edit data that has been added after this point in time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use partitions across multiple filegroups. Once a section of data (eg, for a month once reconciliation has taken place) must be read only, mark the file group as such.

Comment: * Requires Enterprise Edition

Comment: Partitioning can be done with views too.

Comment: Haven't used partitions in the past but sounds like a neat solution to my problem. Will definitely read up on it. Many thanks